# which is the most efficient way of iterating through a large array to store into sqlite in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, query-optimization

lets say that im inserting data into a table under a for loop like this:

```
...
for(let i=0;i<data.length; i++){
    db.run(`INSERT INTO db (a, t, p, q, bM) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`, [data[i].a, data[i].t, data[i].p, data[i].q, data[i].m], (err) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}
...
```

Is it better to use `exec()` instead off `run()` to reduce the number of round trips to the database?

does putting `exec()` under a for-loop, put the sql messages in a queue where when the for-loop ends, the `exec()` function will automatically execute all the queued message in a single instance ? Is that the benefit of using `exec()` over `run()`?

or

because `exec()` is still under a for-loop, it still makes the same roundtrips to the database as `run()` and so there is no diffference betweeen the two methods?

because im working with an array containing 1000s of objects, i want to reduce the number of round trips to the database.

which is the better method, `exec()` or `run()` if it is inside a for loop? is there any difference? if not, can you suggest another method to iterate thru a large array? I'm new to sqlite and databases in general.

Comment: "i have been asking chat gpt for some advice but im getting conflicting information." And are you surprised? Using AI-gennerated content is banned on StackOverflow for exactly that reason. I recommend to [edit] the question from "can you explain why chatgpt contradicts itsel?" to a question which you have on what you tried our thought yourself. Otherwise this question will  peobably be perceived as chatgpt-based and deleted.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it currently seems chatgpt-based and is not about own attempts and thinking.

Comment: i dont have a bone to pick with the contentious environment between chat gpt and stackoverflow. i just want to know the correct answer to my question.

Comment: Make it your question instead a question on the answers you got from chatgpt and StackOverflow users will be happy to help you. Do not go into a pub wearing the wrong sportsclub fan attire and singing their hymn. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the overarching question which is the most efficient way to reduce the number of round trips. You can do this by sending fewer commands. SQLite supports a multi-insert syntax:

```
INSERT INTO 'tablename' ('column1', 'column2', 'column3') VALUES
  ('field-column1-row1', 'field-column1-row-2', 'field-column1-row-3'),
  ('field-column2-row1', 'field-column2-row-2', 'field-column2-row-3'),
...
;
```

Batching these inserts in as few individual calls as possible will be where you save the greatest number of round-trips.

The syntax is here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

`db.exec` imposes a marginally lesser load on the process; the major difference between `db.exec` and `db.run` is that `db.run` returns extra values like `lastID`, which you do not seem to need here.

Comment: which is best practice for working with large arrays? Batch the queries before sending once like you answered? Or iterate thru the for loop multiple times like my starting example?

Comment: Batch. If you look at what other DBs do when importing data from their command lines they always batch. You save some processing steps on multiple levels.